# Can somebody please justify this output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I just want a proper explanation on to why printing __init__method using an object gives output "none".

```
class cars:
    wheels = 4

    def __init__(self):
        self.mil = 10
        self.company = "BMW"

c1 = cars()
print(c1.__init__())
```

Comment: The `__init__` does not return anything - which in python means it returns `None`.

Answer (score 1):

`__init__` doesn't return anything explicitly, therefore it implicitly returns `None`, which is the result you're seeing.